# java: Collect and combine data in a list

Tags: java, java-8, concatenation, java-stream

In my program I have a List of Plants, each plant has a measurement (String), day (int), camera (int), and replicate number(int). I obtain a List of all plants wanted by using filters:

```
List<Plant> selectPlants = allPlants.stream().filter(plant -> passesFilters(plant, filters)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I would like to do now is take all Plants that have the same camera, measurement, and replicate values. And combine them in order of day. So if I have days 1,2,3,5 I would want to find all similar plants and append the values to one plant where the getValues (function).

I added a method to Plant that appends values by just using addAll( new plant values ).

Is there any way of doing this without iterating through the list over and over to find the similar plants, and then sorting each time by day then appending? I'm sorry for the horrible wording of this question.

Comment: There are a couple answers that have figured out how to group the "similar" plants together (assuming that "similar" means they have the same camera, measurement, and replicate values). Now that similar plants have been gathered together, what's to be done with them? Append which values to which plant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [Vakh’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396026/2711488) is correct, it is unnecessarily complex.

Often, the work of implementing your own key class does not pay off. You can use a `List` as a key which implies a slight overhead due to boxing primitive values but given the fact that we do operations like hashing here, it will be negligible.

And sorting doesn’t have to be done by using a `for` loop and, even worse, an anonymous inner class for the `Comparator`. Why do we have streams and lambdas? You can implement the `Comparator` using a lambda like `(p1,p2) -> p1.getDay()-p2.getDay()` or, even better, `Comparator.comparing(Plant::getDay)`.

Further, you can do the entire operation in one step. The `sort` step will create an ordered stream and the collector will maintain the encounter order, so you can use one stream to sort and group:

```
Map<List<?>, List<Plant>> groupedPlants =  allPlants.stream()
  .filter(plant -> passesFilters(plant, filters))
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Plant::getDay))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p ->
     Arrays.asList(p.getMeasurement(), p.getCamera(), p.getReplicateNumber())));
```

That’s all.

Comment: Sorry I have a quick question. What exactly is being stored into the key and value to the map? I noticed that the key is an arraylist of Plants of size 4 while the value is also an arraylist of plants size 3 (for one example).

Comment: No, the key should have the size `3` here, as it’s the result of `Arrays.asList(measurement,camera,replicateNumber)` forming the tuple that you want to be distinct for each group. This key list contains the said values, not `Plant`s (don’t get confused by the `String` representation). As you said in your question, you want to combine all Plants having the same `(measurement,camera,replicateNumber)`. The values can have arbitrary size as each value list contains all `Plant`s for which the key values are equal.

Comment: I'm noticing that after I group the plants. There will be at least one plant where the time values and the regular values do not have the same size, but they do before going into the collection. Why do you think this is? I checked and the two lists are equal before, but not after.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Collectors.groupBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

```
private static class PlantKey {
    private String measurement;
    private int camera;
    private int replicateNumber;
    // + constructor, getters, setters and haschode equals
}

Map<PlantKey, List<Plant>> groupedPlants = 
  allPlants.stream().filter(plant -> passesFilters(plant, filters))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupBy(p -> 
                               new PlantKey(p.getMeasurement(),
                                            p.getCamera(),
                                            p.getReplicateNumber())));

// order the list
for(List values : groupedPlants.values()) {
    Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<Plant>(){
                       @Override
                       public int compare(Plant p1, Plant p2) {
                           return p1.getDay() - p2.getDay();
                       }
                     });
}
```

Comment: You could create a constructor `PlantKey(Plant p)` and your groupBy then becomes: `groupBy(PlantKey::new)`.

Comment: You are right, it would be much more elegant. The final sorting could also be made more elegant using streams and slightly more efficient instanciating the comparator only once.

Answer (score 1):

I would group them by the common characteristics and compare similar results.

```
for(List<Plant> plantGroup : allPlants.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                p -> p.camera+'/'+p.measurement+'/'+p.replicate)).values()) {
    // compare the plants in the same group
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `sorted` which operates on a `stream`

```
selectPlants.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.day)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```